# RequireHttps Fails On Redirects with Parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ssl, https

Besides simply redirecting from HTTP to HTTPS, the [RequireHttps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.requirehttpsattribute(VS.100).aspx) attribute also changes my URL's question mark `?` to `%3F`.  Unsurprisingly, that breaks things.

Why?  How do I fix it?

### scenario:

1. I try to navigate to `http://www.example.com/message/compose`
2. But let's say I don't have permission to view that page.

   ```
   <HandleError()> _
   Public Class MessageController
       Inherits System.Web.Mvc.Controller

       Function Compose() As ActionResult
           ...
           If ... Then
               Throw New Exception(Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized.ToString)
           End If
           ...
           Return View()
       End Function

       ...

   End Class
   ```
3. The action throws an exception.
4. The exception is handled by my Error.aspx page

   ```
   <%@ Page Language="VB" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage(Of System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorInfo)" %>

   <script runat="server">
       Sub Page_Load(ByVal Sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
           If Model.Exception.Message = Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized.ToString Then
               response.redirect("/signin?ReturnUrl=" + Url.Encode(request.Path))
           End If
           ...
       End Sub
   </script>

   ...
   ```
5. I'm redirected to my Sign In page at `http://www.example.com/signin?ReturnUrl=%2fmessage%2fcompose`
6. But I'm using HTTP and not HTTPS. My action requires HTTPS. (That [RemoteRequireHttps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639707/asp-net-mvc-requirehttps-in-production-only/1639831#1639831) inherits from [RequireHttps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.requirehttpsattribute(VS.100).aspx) and overrides its OnAuthorization method to simply disregard localhost.)

   ```
   <HandleError()> _
   Public Class AccountController
       Inherits System.Web.Mvc.Controller

       <RemoteRequireHttps()> _
       Function SignIn() As ActionResult
           ...
       End Function

       ...

   End Class
   ```
7. I'm redirected to `https://www.example.com/signin%3FReturnUrl=%2fmessage%2fcompose`
8. I see this error in my browser:

> Bad Request

It seems that RequireHttps changes my question mark `?` to `%3F`.

Answer (score 1):

We're considering using a URL rewriter like [ISAPI Rewrite](http://www.isapirewrite.com/) to handle things like this before they ever get to your code. Of course, this would only work if you have access to the server.

Also, if you're using IIS 7, I believe it comes with URL rewriting functionality built in.

Comment: It might be a better to handle it in IIS.  I can't think of any uses where it would necessarily have to be at the application level.

Answer (score 1):

My [answer to my own question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685724/requirehttps-fails-in-mvc-preview-2-when-applying-to-accountcontroller-logon/1685774#1685774) here might help (appears to be a bug in MVC 2 Preview 2)

Can I ask why you're not using [Authorize] or a [custom authorization attribute](http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2009/04/09/CustomAuthorizationASPNETMVCFrameworkAuthorizeAttribute.aspx). If you're using .NET authentication you should use [Authorize].

Note: even if you do use [Authorize] it doesnt actually fix the problem you're experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

I've just reengineered this to avoid the question mark (and also exception throws) altogether.

### scenario:

I try to navigate to `http://www.example.com/message/compose`

But let's say I don't have permission to view that page.

```
Public Class MessageController
    Inherits System.Web.Mvc.Controller

    Function Compose() As ActionResult
        ...
        If ... Then
            Return RedirectToAction("SignIn", "Account", New With {.ReturnUrl = Request.Path})
        End If
        ...
        Return View()
    End Function

    ...

End Class
```

I'm redirected to my Sign In page. My route looks like this:

```
routes.MapRoute( _
    "SignIn", _
    "signin/{*ReturnUrl}", _
    New With {.controller = "Account", _
              .action = "SignIn", _
              .ReturnUrl = ""} _
)
```

So that's at address `http://www.example.com/signin/message/compose`

But I'm using HTTP and not HTTPS. My action requires HTTPS.

```
Public Class AccountController
    Inherits System.Web.Mvc.Controller

    <RemoteRequireHttps()> _
    Function SignIn(ByVal ReturnUrl As String) As ActionResult
        ...
    End Function

    ...

End Class
```

I'm redirected to `https://www.example.com/signin/message/compose`

No question mark.  No problem.