# fails in MVC Preview 2 when applying to AccountController.LogOn

Tags: asp.net-mvc, requirehttps

When trying to apply [RequireHttps] to AccountController.Logon in ASP.NET MVC 2 Preview 2 I get the following error :

> ASP.NET detected invalid characters in the URL.

This is because ASP.NET has rewritten my request from

`http://example.com/admin` to

`https://example.com/account/logon%3FReturnUrl=/admin`

It is ASP.NET itself that has added `ReturnURL` (not ASP.NET MVC), but it is the `RequireHttps` attribute that is redirecting and messing up the URL.

The `%3F` instead of `?` is breaking the page.

I think its technically a bug in ASP.NET. Is there a workaround?
I'm thinking maybe a way to handle the 'unauthenticated' event in global.asax - or possibly just fixing the source for RequireHttpsAttribute.

```
    [RequireHttps]
    public ActionResult LogOn()
    {
        return View(DefaultModel);
    }

    <authentication mode="Forms">
       <forms loginUrl="~/account/logon"/>
    </authentication>
```

Here's a  [similar, but different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645999/requirehttps-fails-on-redirects-with-parameters)

**Edit:** I just tried manually entering in `http://example.com/accout/login?cat=dog` and it still redirected to an invalid URL : `account/logon%3Fcat=dog`. I originally thought it was related to a conflict between the membership provider and `[RequireHttps]` but it looks like just a basic bug so I think I'll have to just fix the source myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears fixed in ASP.NET MVC2 RC.

```
 /admin
```

now gets rewritten to the correct URL:

```
 /account/logon?ReturnUrl=/admin
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is a temporary bug in ASP.NET MVC 2 Preview 2 this is what I did :

- Created RequireHttps2 class
- Applied the [RequireHttps2] attribute instead of [RequireHttps]

  public class RequireHttps2Attribute : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
  {

  ```
  public virtual void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
  {
      if (filterContext == null)
      {
          throw new ArgumentNullException("filterContext");
      }

      if (!filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsSecureConnection)
      {
          HandleNonHttpsRequest(filterContext);
      }
  }

  protected virtual void HandleNonHttpsRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
  {
      // only redirect for GET requests, otherwise the browser might not propagate the verb and request
      // body correctly.

      if (!String.Equals(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod, "GET", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
      {
          throw new InvalidOperationException("MUST USE SSL");
      }

      // redirect to HTTPS version of page
      UriBuilder builder = new UriBuilder()
      {
          Scheme = "https",
          Host = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.Host,
          Path = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Path,
          Query = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString.ToString()

          // ORIGINAL CODE : Path = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl // use RawUrl since it works with URL rewriting

      };

      string url = builder.ToString();
      filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(url);
  }
  ```

  }

Comment: I had exactly the same problem, but this is the only post anywhere that I've seen that addressed it! Thanks.

Comment: did you try with MVC 2 RC yet? if not we need to file a bug report !