# How do i conditionally Enable or disable [RequireHttps]

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

```
[RequireHttps]
public class AccountController : BaseWebAppController
```

I need to conditionally enable or disable requirehttps to this controller.
What do I have to do?

Comment: What is your condition? Compile time or runtime?

Answer (score 1):

You could use method described here: [ASP.NET MVC RequireHttps in Production Only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639707/asp-net-mvc-requirehttps-in-production-only)

Comment: The methods are not working while overriding RequireHttpsAttribute

Comment: Sorry, I didn't give exactly link to answer. I mean conditional compilaton, not overriding attribute. This one is correct: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639707/asp-net-mvc-requirehttps-in-production-only/1639831#1639831.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit tricky without knowing what your conditions are but I would go along the route of deriving an attribute from RequireHttpsAttribute and overriding HandleNonHttpsRequest. In that method you should be able to test your condition and react accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
public class ProdOnlyRequireHttpsAttribute : RequireHttpsAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (!Statics.IsPROD()) return;

        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Then

```
[ProdOnlyRequireHttps]
public class HomeController : Controller
```