# Testing with HTTP

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to get an action to fire but getting the following error...

> ArgumentException: IDX20108: The address specified '[PII is hidden.
> For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]' is not valid
> as per HTTPS scheme. Please specify an https address for security
> reasons. If you want to test with http address, set the RequireHttps
> property on IDocumentRetriever to false. (Parameter 'address')

How do I set the `RequireHttps` property to false?

The line triggering the error is...

```
await HttpContext.ChallengeAsync("Schema", new AuthenticationProperties() {});
```

Comment: I cannot.  It has to be HTTP

Comment: Then you won't be testing the real application endpoint. That error is generated by Identity Server which always uses HTTPS

Comment: There should be local testing that's possible right?

Comment: Can you please provide some code and startup file if any.

Comment: This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639707/asp-net-mvc-requirehttps-in-production-only.

Comment: That's more how to enable it? It defaults to true.  I want to turn it off.

Comment: Just added the line triggering the error.